# RetNet: Why Diagonalize A Square Matrix?

Tags: neural-networks, math

The paragraph before eq. (3) in [The RetNet paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.08621.pdf) says to diagonalize the $R^{d{\times}d}$ matrix $A$. I am confused as to why one would not just use a vector?

One of the arguments that I have heard on why you would diagonalize a matrix is that they are easy for exponentiation, but I am not sure if that *really* is the reason here.